# Two values as DISTINCT in Neo4j query

Tags: neo4j

I am sending a query to `Neo4j` database and I want to return only the items that have two numbers - `tsneX` and `tsneY` as a distinct 'point'. So, `tsneX` can be equal to `tsneX`, but the second number `tsneY` should not in that case. Here is my query:

```
MATCH (c:Cell)-[ex:EXPRESSES]->(g:Gene { geneName: "' + geneName + '" }) 
RETURN ex.expr, c.tsneX, c.tsneY;
```

So, I want smth like

```
MATCH (c:Cell)-[ex:EXPRESSES]->(g:Gene { geneName: "' + geneName + '" }) 
WITH DISTINCT (c.tsneX, c.tsneY) AS point
RETURN ex.expr, point;
```

> Example:

```
    ex.expr  c.tsneX  c.tsneY
1.    4        1.2      1.2
2.    5        2.1      3.3
3.    1        1.2      1.2
```

One of them - 1st or 3rd need to be dropped since their `tsneX` and `tsneY` coordinates are equal respectively to each other. So, I would want only 1st and 2nd to be returned but 3rd to be dropped since `ex.expr` is higher in the 1st one.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you clarify more about what you want here? Such as an example result set, showing how you would want it filtered to get the results you need?

Comment: Oh, I just need a way to combine two values - tsneX and tsneY into an object and force it to be distinct if both values are not equal respectively to another such `point` object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want the pair of [c.tsneX, c.tsneY], and in the case there's more results with the same point you only want the higheset ex.expr. This should do the trick:

```
MATCH (c:Cell)-[ex:EXPRESSES]->(g:Gene { geneName: "' + geneName + '" }) 
RETURN [c.tsneX, c.tsneY] AS point, max(ex.expr) as expr
```

If you want the point as an object rather than a list, you can instead do:

```
{x:c.tsneX, y:c.tsneY} AS point
```

In either case, the `max(ex.expr)` aggregation function will ensure that the remaining non-aggregation value, `point`, is distinct.